# How do I tap coordinates inside of a specific element with selenium TouchActions python?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, mobile, touch

The Selenium ActionChains module includes the ability to move to an element with offset provided an x and y coordinate like so:
`ActionChains(browser).move_to_element_with_offset(x-offset, y-offser).click().perform()`
Which is useful to test responsiveness of elements nested inside other elements such as a react element.

The Selenium TouchActions module includes something similar except the coordinates are relative to the viewport. My TouchActions script looks like this:

```
TouchActions(browser).tap_and_hold(x-offset, y-offset).release(x-offset, y-offset).perform()
```

This script does not activate the expected event for me; however, this script does:

```
element = browser.find_element_by_XPath(//img)
TouchActions(browser).tap(element).perform()
```

The tap occurs at the center of the element, which is useful; however, I need the ability to repeat the tap again at different parts of the element to test for the event. 
**ADDITIONAL NOTE:**
The expected events can be fired manually.

Comment: Are you using appium driver or Chrome driver? will click action not activate your event?

Comment: latest selenium build and chromedriver 2.43. The click action doesn't activate the event. The tap action does. I'd prefer not to shift my dependencies if possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the implementation of the app i was working on had a feature that was accessible via the native os version, but not via its web version.

This question could have been solved easier if i had provided details of the specific application I was trying to test.

The provided uses of Selenium in the question work fine. Here's [the documentation](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.touch_actions.html#selenium.webdriver.common.touch_actions.TouchActions.long_press)